# How much is considered bleeding?

Tags: display, led

I got a new LED panel (Dell's 1080p B+RGLED) and it is great as far as color goes. Blacks are also very dark.

However, the center 1/3 to 1/2 of the screen at the both the top and bottom edges has a slightly brighter black. It is only noticable when the screen is covered entirely in a black image. It's not exactly "flashlighting" that I've seen elsewhere, as that tends to be very prominent. This is a barely noticable glow, along the top and bottom edges, slightly less visible on the top edge.

I tried to take a photo to illustrate the issue, but because of the glossiness/reflection of the display, I've had issues. I'll try again with a better camera in a few days.

My real question is, is this a defect? I have noticed other LED panels with similar glows along different edges (my Toshiba laptop glows along the sides particularly, instead of the top/bottom).

<sub>I tried replacing it however the replacement was faulty. I am not entirely sure I want to mess with getting a third replacement.</sub>

It almost appears to be be a gradient. With the screen getting ever so slightly brighter as it reaches the bottom edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a defect but it's a defect that almost every display panel is going to have to some degree.  [Here's an article](http://bit.ly/xhQDzt) that explains the whole issue.  Quoting from that article:

> Unfortunately, almost all LCD panels suffer from at least a small
>   amount of backlight bleed because the opacity of LCD panels is not
>   enough to block all light, though it only causes problems if it can be
>   easily detected by the human eye.

Only you can decide if the problem is bad enough to warrant a repair or replacement of the display.  You might check Newegg or Amazon reviews to see if this particular model of display is known for this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link. My issue is nowhere near the severity pictured, which seems to point to one of those "almost all" cases. I've seen worse.